# Paypal IPN processing after payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have IPN controller which is validating IPN and then validating some fields according with  [that article](http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=PayPal)

After user clicking pay on paypal website the ipn sending to my `ipn controller` and at the same time user getting redirected back to my web site(`after paypal controller`) from paypal web site.

But the problem is, there is not enough time for my `IPN controller` to finish all the logic and user landed to my website on `after paypal controller` before IPN processing finished. So i cant say to user is there was any error or is it was successful.

My be some one may share their experience with that? What I can do?
I would redirect user from paypal back to my website only after ipn processing finished, so i could be able to say to user is it was successful or not, etc.

On my `after paypal controller` i want to check if the ipn processing was successful and than display related message.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -3):

IPN is separate from the end users experience.

You need 3 pages/actions: 
one for if paypal said "payment confirmed" 
another for if paypal said "payment failed" 
- these 2 pages mean nothing, the user could hack the site to see these pages, they are just there to let the user know what's going on.

Third page/action is for IPN, it's just a listener that waits for paypal's response. Once you get the response then you check against it to make sure everything is ok:

- Make sure your email was paid
- Make sure the price is right
- Updates your db with "Paid!" marker, yada yada

You could then have a simple binding to ("Paid!") that updates when the user 'postsback' or you could have ajax do it async.

-- As a final point, I'm genuinely trying to find out here how to process/test the IPN and your obviously unresearched question has wasted my time. Do some research man.

Comment: If my moderately sarcastic rant upset you or anyone else I apologise. I don't think that my tone should detract from the value of an answer though...